# Retrieving object from a node in Firebase if the node has currentuser.uid object and display in my UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

My db structure is in my iOS app

[image]

I need to retrieve all fridges that the current user's id and display in a table view. After browsing through all threads for a good amount of time I haven't got the right answer.

Here is my Swift code that doesn't do what I need. I believe I am messing up with queries:

```
let fridgeDB = Database.database().reference()
    let fridgeDBRef = fridgeDB.child("fridges")
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}

    let queryRef = fridgeDBRef.queryOrdered(byChild: uid)
    queryRef.observe(.childAdded) { snapshot in
        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
        print("snapshotValue: \(snapshotValue)")
        let name = snapshotValue["FridgeName"]!
        let fridge = Fridge()
        fridge.fridgeName = name as! String
        self.fridgeUnits.append(fridge)
        self.configureTableView()
        self.fridgeList.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty close.

Your query needs to do two things 1) define the node to query on, and 2) define what your want to query for.

The node you want to query on is actually the uid, and you want to query to see if it's true.

```
let itemsRef = self.ref.child("fridges")
let thisUserQuery = itemsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: uid).queryEqual(toValue: true)
thisUserQuery.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    guard let foundFridges = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {return}
    for fridge in foundFridges {
        let name = fridge.childSnapshot(forPath: "FridgeName").value as! String
        print(fridge.key, name)
    }
})
```

Comment: this works well. Thanks for that! I changed `item.childSnapshot` to `fridge.childSnapshot`. But reload tableview stopped working. The new item is visible only after logout/login.

Comment: now for some reason it has stopped working, throws Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "l1GIK43GCUbdnnyYsrQnO3JLnjV2" at /fridges to your security rules for better performance. These are the rules:  `{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
      }
    },
    "fridges": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null",
    }
  }
}`

Comment: @Stormwright Thanks for catching the 'item' typo. I fixed it in the answer. That message is standard and can safely be ignored during development - it will not affect accessing your database. It's specifically to make queries go faster by indexing the nodes you search on. See [Indexing Your Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data)